# EOF error from input()

Tags: python

```
while 1:
     print function()
     input()
```

This returns an EOF error I am just try to make it run the next iteration of the loop when I press enter

Please help, thank you

Comment: It looks like you're just starting to learn Python, so you should be learning Python 3. Python 2 won't be supported anymore in a few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raw_input` as opposed to `input` (`input` is for Python 3 (mainly))

Also if that still doesn't work, try assigning a variable to `input()`, or use an empty string between the parenthesis

IE

`a = input()`

`raw_input('')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input` in Python2.

`raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in python3.